# Записать переменную полученную через callback

Tags: jquery, callback

Как получить данные из response в переменную res?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('submit', '#forma', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $that = $(this);
    formData = new FormData($that.get(0));
    var table = $('input[name="table"]').val();
    
    console.log(table);
    var editor = tinyMCE.EditorManager.get('textArea');
    if(editor){
        formData.set('save_arr[text]', editor.getContent());
    }
    var NewArr = {
        id: $('input[name="napravlenie_id"]:enabled').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(),
        table: $('input[name="napravlenie_table"]:enabled').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(),
        name: $('input[name="napravlenie_name"]:enabled').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(),
        price: $('input[name="napravlenie_price"]:enabled').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(),
        map: $('input[name="napravlenie_map"]:enabled').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()
    };
    if (NewArr['id'].length != 0) {
        SaveData(NewArr);
    }
    
    var res;
    SendSaveForma(function(response){
        res = response; console.log(response)
    },$that, formData, table);

    console.log(res)
  });
});


function SendSaveForma(callback, $that, formData, table) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: $that.attr('action'),
        type: $that.attr('method'),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){
            var response = 'tttttttttttt';
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var res;
SendSaveForma(function(response){
    res = response;
    console.log("RESPONSE " + response);
    console.log("RES " +res);
    // И здесь же обработка
},$that, formData, table);
```

Либо использовать промисы или переходить на `async/await`.

Comment: не получается, возвращает undefined.

Comment: Если `response`  равно `undefined`, то почему `res` должна иметь другое значение? Проверяйте есть ли ответ о того запроса, что Вы отправляете в функции.

Comment: Проверяю, в `console.log(response)` - я получаю значение, в `res` `undefined`

Comment: Я передаю строку - `console.log(response)` выводит `текст строки`

Comment: Если Вы пр прежнему присваиваете определяете `res` после вызова функции и  присваиваете значение вне `callback`, то это не удивительно. `var` в  `success` Вас не спасёт, т.к. он далеко не всегда делает переменную глобальной.

Comment: Как проверяете `res`? Код в студию!

Comment: `res` проверяю через `console.log(res)`.

Comment: Где конкретно Вы его вызываете? Приведите пожалуйста полный код примера в вопросе.

Comment: указал полный код примера. в `console.log(response)` получаю значение `tttttttttttt`, в `console.log(res)` получаю значение `undefined`

Comment: Посмотрел. Вы выводите res вне асинхронного запроса. Поэтому у Вас и undefined. Запрос и присвоение значения просто не успевает отработать к моменту вывода. Либо переносите логику обработки в callback либо промисы или async/await/

Answer (score 0):

@Streletz, спасибо. Я одной формой отправляю разные данные в разные таблицы. И мне надо быть уверенным что в первую таблицу данные записались. Получаю id строки и записываю остальные данные в другую таблицу parent_id = id. Перенес SaveData(NewArr) в SendSaveForma. Не знаю на сколько это верно, но мои познания jquery нулевые.

```
SendSaveForma(function(response){
    if (NewArr['id'].length != 0 && response != 0) {
        SaveData(NewArr, response);
    }
},$that, formData, table);




function SaveData(NewArr, parent_id){
$('.loud_save').css({'display': 'block'});
$.ajax({
    url: "./",
    type: "POST",
    data: {DatanewForm: NewArr},
    success: function(res){
        console.log(parent_id)
    }
});
};
```